# Visual Studio 2013 Slow Build Slow Startup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, offline-mode

I've been having a very weird problem with Visual Studio 2013 Professional and it wasn't like this 3 weeks before.

I have a C# solution with 25 projects all saved to my local C:\ drive. None of the project files are in my network shared drive.

1. I try opening the solution, but it takes 20-30 seconds for the splash screen to show up, but it used to be fractions of a second 3 weeks before.
2. After the splash screen, it takes another 20-30 seconds for the IDE to show up and load all my projects. But it used to take only 5 seconds 3 weeks before.
3. I try to do a build of the entire solution (Debug or Release mode, doesn't matter) and it takes 7-10 MINUTES to complete. However, 3 weeks before, it used to take less than 10 SECONDS to complete successfully.
4. Now, I disconnect the ethernet cable attached to my workstation and then do a rebuild (Clean and then Build) of the same solution. Essentially, I'm disconnecting from the internal network & internet. What a surprise, the rebuild took less than 10 seconds to complete just like 3 weeks before.

Questions:

1. Why does Visual Studio depend on the network? (By the way I have already switched off all Source Control & Team Foundation Server & have not signed in with a Microsoft account & switched off all settings syncing and it still did not matter).
2. Is there a switch or configuration setting in Visual Studio 2013 such that Visual Studio will never ever need anything from the network/internet? How do I block Visual Studio from accessing the network?

Comment: What?  Why were *all* of the comments wiped out?

Comment: Your project or some dependency is on a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try 2 things that might speed things up (a lot!):

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Extensions and updates -> Uncheck "Automatically check for updates"
2. Go to Tools -> Options -> Startup -> At startup select "Show empty environment"

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There could be many connection strings in connection strings file which cannot be able to be connected from your PC. This was the cause of slowness of Visual Studio.

Regards